# Algolia search where string attribute matches a given string

Tags: algolia

I have the following index structure in algolia

[image]

I need to perform a query search where the email attribute matches a given email address i.e return all records where email attribute will match that email. I have read about filtering and faceting and I've also tried to apply it in android but it does not do the filtering that I need.

```
 // Init Algolia.
    MainActivity.index = MainActivity.client.getIndex( "recsD" );


    // Pre-build query.
    query = new Query();
    query.setFacets( "email:"+ FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace( ".","" ) );
    //query.setFilters( "email:"+ FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace( ".","" ) );
    query.setAttributesToRetrieve( "Note", "date", "time", "audio", "uid" );
    query.setAttributesToHighlight( "Note" );
    query.setHitsPerPage( HITS_PER_PAGE );
```

With the above code I'm able to fetch all results including the ones where email address doesn't match. What is it that I am not doing right? How can I achieve something like

```
SELECT * FROM recsD WHERE email='lilsaimo@gmailcom'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from using `setFacets` instead of `setFilters`. Quoting Algolia's documentation on **facets**:

> Facets to retrieve. If not specified or empty, no facets are retrieved. The special value * may be used to retrieve all facets.

So using `setFacets("foo", "bar")` will ask the Algolia engine to return in the results the facet values for facet "foo" and "bar". This alone won't do any filtering!

If you want to filter results to only keep the ones matching `foo=bar`, you should:

- Enable faceting on the `foo` attribute, [either in the settings or for this query](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/?language=instantsearchjs#scope)
- Set the filter `filters="foo:bar"`, as shown in the [filters documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/) under [facet filters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/?language=instantsearchjs#facet-filters)

Getting back to your android code, you should rather try:

```
// Pre-build query.
query = new Query();
query.setFacets("email");
query.setFilters( "email:"+ FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace( ".","" ) );
```